# Where are the iCloud Drive Libraries icons located?

Tags: mac, icloud, macos

Some apps, like Preview, Pages, or Keynote have folders with different default preview icons publicly visible in the iCloud Drive folder. Where are those icons stored?

[image: These ones]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found it. iCloud daemon (`bird`) stores info of all the iCloud containers in:

```
~/Library/Application Support/CloudDocs/session/containers
```

The info is stored in a plist file with the name of the container for example:

```
iCloud.com.pvieito.Example.plist
```

And the icons are stored in a folder with the name of the container:

```
iCloud.com.pvieito.Example/40x40_iOS.png
iCloud.com.pvieito.Example/80x80_iOS.png
iCloud.com.pvieito.Example/120x120_iOS.png
```

Answer (score -1):

All Mac Icons are stored here:

Open a new Finder window from the OS X Desktop and hit Command+Shift+G (or go to the “Go” menu and choose “Go To Folder”. Then paste this in:

`/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/`

You should find what you're looking for in there.

*Edit: If you can't find what you're looking for above, it must be the app icon, which you should be able to find here: `/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/`*

Comment: No, there are the default System icons. I want the icons that an iOS app set as iCloud icons and then appear in macOS as the superimposed icon over a folder. They should be downloaded and cached from iCloud servers.

Comment: @pvieito can you provide an image example? I'm not following...

Comment: I added an image to the question. Those folders are not iCloud Drive folders but iCloud app containers exposed to the Finder as folders with the icon overlay I want to change.

Comment: Oh. For changing it. I don't believe it's modifiable.

Comment: Well, I don't want to modify it, I want to delete it as it has cached an old version of the app icon. In iOS and iCloud.com appears the new icon but in the Mac is the old one.

Comment: @pvieito Try updating/reinstalling the app?